# I don't want to include encoded strings in search result sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am using encoding before saving data into SQL Server. I am facing problem when i perform search.

**Explanation:**
User saved string "**Table isn't auto**" But this string saved in SQL Server as `"Table isn&#39;t auto"`

apostrophe encoded to `&#39;`

When user search "3" then this record is coming from sql query. I wanted to removed this type of records.

Comment: It is easily done by [not](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/) storing encoded strings in SQL Server.

Comment: @GSerg thanks! Is there any help for the current approach?

Answer (score 1):

Your can use XML data type which supports XML/HTML encoded entities. Please see the following example.

```
select cast('Q &amp; A' as XML).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)' );
```

You can easily create a function to return decoded strings and search within.